# Transfers from 3 days ago still "locked" in Monero GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-confirmation, transaction-unlock-time

Two 100 XMR transfers from Poloniex to my Monero GUI wallet (Windows 64) were still locked after 2 days, and rebooting. Day 3, still locked, I shut it down, turned it on again, and now unlocked. Any thoughts?

eg, Tx ID: 9b9cb99c0359ab267bb253505d358f13b57c0600c9903cf490af581ddbc497c6

Answer (score 1):

Normally, transfers are locked for 10 blocks. If yours were still locked, it means either node node was failing to sync to the chain, or the wallet failed to refresh from the node. You'd see that if the wallet was claiming the same height for a few days, though I'm not sure if it displays that promoinently.

Of course, it could also be a bug in the GUI or the monero code it uses. You may want to check the logs for the daemon (~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log) and the GUI wallet (on the console, I'm not sure it logs to a file, but check for a monero-wallet-gui.log wherever the binary is) for errors or suspicious messages which may give a lead.